# How to set incremental marks?

Tags: cursor-movement, mark

I'm used to set marks with `m<char>` where `<char>` is any character I choose and then reaching the marks with `` ]` `` or `` [` ``.

I'm wondering if it is possible to use a command to set a mark with an **incremental index** instead of a character, avoiding to override marks previously set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing built in to vim, but you can script something like this:

```
fu! s:IncrementalMark() abort
    let b:index_mark=get(b:, 'index_mark', -1)+1
    " configure, which marks to use
    let marks='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    return 'm'.marks[b:index_mark%strlen(marks)]
endfu
nnoremap <silent><expr> <leader>m <sid>IncrementalMark()
```

Use the `marks` variable, to configure which marks are actually allowed to be overwritten by this function. If you e.g. want to set the mark a yourself, then remove the a from this variable.

Note, that since marks are buffer-local, so will this function start with the first mark again, once you switch buffers, so you can have the same (lowercase) mark in several buffers.

Comment: Great answer! I remapped it to `mm`, and using a recursive mapping it works as expected with plugins like *Vim-Signature*.
`nmap <expr> mm <SID>#IncrementalMark()`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understood what you wanted. But if you want to cycle through all the available local marks from `a` to `z`, then the following mapping should allow you to do so:

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>m
            \ :<c-u>if !exists('marklist') \|\| marklist == [] <bar>
            \     let marklist = map(range(98, 122), "nr2char(v:val)") <bar>
            \     execute 'normal! ma' <bar>
            \ else <bar>
            \     execute 'normal! m' . marklist[0] <bar>
            \     let marklist = marklist[1:] <bar>
            \ endif<cr>
```

If you hit `<leader>m`, the first time it should set the mark `a` where the cursor is, the second time the mark `b`, etc.